# Query with multiple OR using parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am using Parse.com (JS) for my current project. A simple thing in SQL is driving me nuts with Parse.com, I have read the documentation, but I must say I have trouble understanding correctly the "object" approach.

Anyway, what I need to do is to apply multiple "OR" to a query. Let's say I have three tables :

```
 UserObject(uid, username, password)
 ResponseObject(rid, _userid, _questionid, response) // not used here
 QuestionObject(qid, questionTitle, _userid)
 _userid are pointers to the User table
 _questionid is a pointer to the Question table
```

I first need to select users starting with "mat" from the User table, I do :

```
var UserObject = Parse.Object.extend("UserObject");
var query = new Parse.Query(UserObject);
query. startsWith("username", "mat");\
query.find({
       success: function(results) { etc...
```

In results I now have an array of the users I need. Now I need to select all the question in the Question table where _userid matches this array. I understand I can use the Parse.Query.or as follow :

```
var QuestionObject = Parse.Object.extend("QuestionObject");
var query1 = new Parse.Query(QuestionObject);
query1.equalTo("userid", results[0].get('uid'));
var query2 = new Parse.Query(QuestionObject);
query2.equalTo("userid", results[1].get('uid'));
var mainQuery = new Parse.Query.or(query1, query2);
mainQuery.find({...})
```

But I have no idea how big results is, and if I have 50 users back, I don't want to use Parse.Query.or 50 times ! So I am sure there is an easy solution, but I am stuck ! I'd like to pass directly "results" to the new query or something like that !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No  need for `Parse.Query.or()`.  `Parse.Query` provides `containedIn()` that will match if the value of an object's property is one among some array of values.

(The question states that `userId` on the `Question` object is a pointer.  That's a great choice, but the name "userId" is a confusing choice.  Is it an id or an object?  I hope an object, and the remainder of this answer assumes that).

```
// results is an array of Parse.User from a prior query
var QuestionObject = Parse.Object.extend("QuestionObject");
var query = new Parse.Query(QuestionObject);
query.containedIn("userid", results);
query.find(...)
```

More fully, and with promises...

```
var userQuery = new Parse.Query("UserObject");
userQuery.startsWith("username", "mat");
userQuery.find().then(function(userObjects) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("QuestionObject");
    query.containedIn("userid", userObjects);
    return query.find();
 }).then(function(questions) {
     // questions are Questions who's users' username begins with 'mat'
 });
```

Comment: Well, that's fantastic ! Actually it is not call "userId" but just "user" in the DB and they are object so everything work as expected ! Thanks